# Dental plosive with no apical obstruction

Tags: phonetics, consonants, articulation, stops

Can I have a paper which describes dental plosives by the two rows of teeth as opposed to contacting the dental area with the tongue ?? I mean the air needs obstructed and the posterior most place of articulation defines the phoneme but nobody who I socialize with is doing it. they just use the two teeth rows, so can I have a reference please?

Comment: To clarify: are you looking for a paper or book on phonetics that describes a consonant (likely a fricative) that is produced, either in natural language or in impaired speech, by contacting the top and bottom teeth, with the tongue remaining in its resting position?

Comment: Its just a plosive consonant with the teeth though.. "A bidental plosive" as the other comment suggests.

Comment: Well, I didn't think of a plosive, despite you saying "plosive", because that seemed clearly impossible as lines of teeth are not airtight, and the rest of what you wrote was also unclear, probably explaining the close vote and my clarification request.

Comment: So really in a dental plosive the air is coagulated behind the tongue while it is contacting the teeth????

Comment: I don't think a *purely* dental plosive, with the tip of the tongue touching the teeth but the blade not contacting the upper palate's alveolar ridge *at all*, is common in non-impaired speech. Denti-alveolar stops (where the tip of the tongue does touch the teeth, but the airflow is primarily stopped by the blade touching the upper palate) are common, and then you can have distinctions between laminal and apical alveolar stops, and stops made with the tongue making contact further back in the palate. My point is that a "purely" dental stop won't be a stop for most people, as it'd let air out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not seen all papers in phonology, but I don't think that a *bidental plosive* or a *bidental stop* (that would be technical terms for that sound) was ever described in literature. A *[bidental fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_bidental_fricative)* /h̪͆/ is described as a marginal phoneme occurring as an allophone of another voiceless fricative in Northeast Caucasian languages, see [Are there conlangs using constructed sounds?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/116/142) and the answer of J. Siebeneichler there. The bidental fricative is also observed in distordered speech. In disordered speech, there is also a [bidental percussive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidental_consonant), [ʭ], produced by striking the teeth against each other (gnashing or chattering the teeth).

Comment: Moreover, a bidental plosive would be just too hard for most people to perform consistently. The air isn't obstructed enough. Even just using one set of teeth and the lips to fully occlude the air and produce a labiodental plosive is vanishingly rare, according to Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_labiodental_stop